# In a set of N people, how many people share birthdays with someone else in the set?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The famous [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) runs as follows: in a set of $n$ randomly chosen people, what is the probability that some pair of them share a birthday? The following question is an extension of that famous problem.

Given a set of $n$ randomly chosen people, there is a probability that $k$ people in the set share a birthday with someone else in the set. For a given $n$, what is the most likely $k$? Also, for a given $n$, what is the most likely configuration of birthday sharing, i.e. how many pairs, triplets, etc.?

Note: I am assuming that there are 366 birthdays in a year and that each birthday is equally likely.

Comment: note a group is a mathematical object in math  not the same as a set.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Should have spotted the mismatched mathematical terminology. Edited the question. Thanks :D

Comment: the reason the original problem is so low is because of how many ways there are to choose pairs of people in 23 people there's 253 ways to choose pairs.  In general there's  $${n!\over k!(n-k)!} = \binom nk$$ ways to choose k people out of n.

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2ey9a70yY0   to help you out.

Comment: This paper (and references) can be relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.3493.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ideas that may  help to get started, presenting an exact
formula for eventual verification of results by probabilistic methods,
which  the reader  is invited  to contribute.   Supposing we  have $m$
possible birthdays and $n$ people we get the marked species

$$\mathfrak{S}_{=m}(\mathfrak{P}_{=0}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathfrak{P}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathfrak{P}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{U}\mathcal{Z}))$$

with generating function

$$G(z, u) = (\exp(uz)-uz+z)^m.$$

With this generating function we count the number of configurations of
$n$ samples  from $m$  birthdays where  $k$ of  them are  sharing with
someone else in the configuration. Extracting coefficients we find

$$n! [z^n] [u^k] (\exp(uz)-uz+z)^m
\\ = n! [z^n] [u^k] \sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} \exp(quz)
z^{m-q} (1-u)^{m-q}
\\ = n! [u^k] \sum_{q=\max(0, m-n)}^m 
{m\choose q} [z^{n+q-m}] \exp(quz)
 (1-u)^{m-q}
\\ = n! [u^k] \sum_{q=\max(0, m-n)}^m {m\choose q}
\frac{q^{n+q-m} u^{n+q-m}}{(n+q-m)!}
 (1-u)^{m-q}
\\ = n! \sum_{q=\max(0, m-n)}^m {m\choose q}
\frac{q^{n+q-m}}{(n+q-m)!}
[u^{k-n+m-q}] (1-u)^{m-q}
\\ = n! (-1)^{k-n+m} \sum_{q=\max(0, m-n)}^m {m\choose q}
\frac{q^{n+q-m}}{(n+q-m)!} (-1)^q {m-q\choose m-q-(n-k)}
\\ = n! (-1)^{k-n+m} \sum_{q=\max(0, m-n)}^m {m\choose q}
\frac{q^{n+q-m}}{(n+q-m)!} (-1)^q {m-q\choose n-k}.$$

Now observe that

$${m\choose q} {m-q\choose n-k}
= \frac{m!}{q! (n-k)! (m-q-(n-k))!}
\\ = {m\choose n-k} {m-(n-k)\choose q}$$

and we get

$$n! (-1)^{k-n+m} {m\choose n-k} \sum_{q=\max(0, m-n)}^m 
\frac{q^{n+q-m}}{(n+q-m)!} (-1)^q {m-(n-k)\choose q}.$$

We can  re-write this one more  time to get a  binomial coefficient to
enforce the lower limit, using

$$\frac{q^{n+q-m}}{(n+q-m)!} {m-(n-k)\choose q}
= \frac{q^{n+q-m}}{q!} {k\choose n+q-m}
\frac{(m-(n-k))!}{k!}$$

to get

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
m! (-1)^{k-n+m} {n\choose k} \sum_{q=1}^m 
\frac{q^{n+q-m}}{q!} (-1)^q {k\choose n+q-m}.}$$

Working with the  month of the birthday  as opposed to the  day in the
year we  get twelve  possibilities and the  following sequence  of the
most likely $k$ when querying $n$ people starting at $n=1$ and ranging
to $n=36$:

$$0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
\\  17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
\ldots $$

What  we  see here  that  for  $n\ge m$  the  behavior  appears to  be
dominated by  a linear  term. Same for  e.g. $32$  different birthdays
ranging from $n=1$ to $n=72$:

$$0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 
\\ 12, 12, 14, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
\\ 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
\\ 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 65,
\ldots $$

Looking at the  intial and the terminal segments of  these data we see
that with $n$ small compared to $m$ the largest group of people is the
group of singletons not sharing with anyone else, which is as we would
expect. On  the other hand with  $n$ large compared to  $m$ almost all
elements are  sharing with someone  else, e.g.  of $72$  birthdays the
most  likely case  is  that  $65$ of  them  are  sharing, leaving  $7$
singletons. The following  plot shows the fraction of  values that are
sharing for twelve birthdays.

[image: Twelve birthdays]

This plot shows  the same statistic for $366$  birthdays with $n=1$
to $n=320$ people.

[image: Three-hundred and sixty six birthdays]

The Maple code for anyone wanting  to work with these statistics is
as follows.   The enumeration routine  can be optimized but  it yields
confirmation results in  a sufficient number of cases and  we have the
closed form, of course.

```
with(plots);

ENUM :=
proc(n, m)
option remember;
local ind, gf, d, mset, sh;

    gf := 0;

    for ind from m^n to 2*m^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, m);
        mset := convert(d[1..n], `multiset`);

        sh := add(`if`(p[2] < 2, 0, p[2]), p in mset);
        gf := gf + u^sh;
    od;

    gf;
end;

ENUMCF := (n, m, k) -> coeff(ENUM(n, m), u, k);

XCF :=
(n, m, k) -> n!*(-1)^(k-n+m)
*add(binomial(m, q)*q^(n+q-m)/(n+q-m)!*(-1)^q
     *binomial(m-q, n-k), q=max(0, m-n)..m);

XCF2 :=
(n, m, k) -> n!*(-1)^(k-n+m)*binomial(m, n-k)
*add(q^(n+q-m)/(n+q-m)!*(-1)^q*binomial(m-(n-k), q),
     q=max(0, m-n)..m);

XCF3 :=
(n, m, k) -> m!*(-1)^(k-n+m)*binomial(n,k)
*add(q^(n+q-m)/q!*(-1)^q*binomial(k, n+q-m), q=1..m);

MXK :=
(n, m) ->
sort([seq([k, XCF3(n, m, k)], k=0..n)],
    (p1, p2) -> p1[2] < p2[2])[n+1][1];

PL := (n, m) ->
pointplot([seq([k, XCF3(n, m, k)], k=0..n)], `connect`);

PLMX := (n1, n2, m) ->
pointplot([seq([n, MXK(n, m)/n], n=n1..n2)], `connect`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Letting $m=$ number of days, $n=$ number of people, $k=$ number of people with shared birthdays. Then $j=n-k=$ number of "singletons".

The problem is equivalent to the following urn-and-balls problem: place randomly $n$ balls uniformly inside $m$ urns, find $P(j)$ , distribution of the number of single occupancy urns (singletons).

A simple (perhaps too simple) Poissonization approximation gives

$$E[j]\approx n\, e^{-n/m} \tag{1}$$

We can expect that asymptotically $j$ tends to a normal, so that the most probable value is near the mean. 
A graph for the average fraction of shared birthdays ($1-E[j]/n$), under the above approximation and for $m=366$ is shown below. It agrees quite well with the graph from Marko Riedel's answer.

[image]

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.3493.pdf) studies some asymptotic approximations in more detail.

---

*Edit*
Actually, there's no need to do a Poissonization approximation to compute the mean. The probability of a given urn of being a singleton is
$ \frac{n}{m} (1-\frac{1}{m})^{n-1} $, hence

$$ E(j)=n \left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n-1} \tag{2}$$

Obviously, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are asympotically equivalent for large $m,n$.